# Switch Terminal gets messy when using 'screen' command after the first time

Tags: terminal, switching

I am entering my switch using these two commands

```
stty -F /dev/ttyS0 9600 cs8 -cstopb -parenb
screen /dev/ttyS0
```

The first time I get into the switch's terminal its fine, but after that, I need to restart the PC to re-enter the switch again since things become messy after the first time

Look at this screenshot to know what "messy" means:
[image: messy switch terminal]

It's an Alleid Telesis switch.

Any advice/solutions?
Best